# How to select keyboard's type for IOS with react native

Tags: ios, iphone, react-native, reactive-programming, keyboard-events

For example: in login page, when I try to read mail adress or any information, defult keyboard type opened. But I need to mail keyboard type for preessing easily to "@"

how to get I configure keyboard types? Is it optional?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specifiy the keyboard via the `keyboardType` prop of TextInput:

```
<TextInput
keyboardType='email-address'
//other props

/>
```

Read more here [react-native-docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/textinput.html#keyboardtype)